# CSS Shadow laying over div / content

Tags: html, css, shadow

I want the shadow to be behind the section. I've tried all the methods but still cannot find  a way to figure it out .

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZ82j/)

HTML

```
<section id="features" class="shadow">
    <div class="container">Content</div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section {
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    z-index:20
}

#features {
    padding:4rem 0;
    background:#018CB8
}

.container {
    color:#FFF;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:55rem;
    width:90%
}

.shadow:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    bottom:0;
    left:10%;
    right:10%;
    width:80%;
    height:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:100%;
    border-radius:100%
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your example right down:

Currently only `z-index: -1` works, which has me confused.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/CZ82j/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="shadow">Content</div>
```

CSS

```
.shadow {
    padding: 4rem 0;
    background: #018CB8;
    color:#FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 55rem;
    width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.shadow:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    bottom:0px;
    left:10%;
    right:10%;
    width:80%;
    height:50%;
    border-radius:100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that would be kind of solution when you are not using z-indexes, but if you want to have the shadow over another section / div to give a feeling that div is on top of the other ones ... what would be the solution ? [Have look here to see what I'm talking about - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZ82j/4/)

Comment: With the current method, you would need to wrap the `.shadow` with the div you want to be overlapped and give it any `z-index` value and `position: relative;`. [Like in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/CZ82j/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZ82j/2/).

I added a `margin-bottom: 40px` to center the shadow. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Sorry, no, have a look at the first answer.